# Running .cmd with 32 bit launcher?

Tags: sccm

I have spent a lot of hours trying to figure out this simple thing I want to accomplish. I have a .cmd file with one line: `sfc /scannow`
I wrapped this into a package with the command line as a program at: `cmd /c sfc.cmd` and this is set to install as required and hidden. (I can look at the cbs log if this actually did run).
So then it get's deployed and downloaded to the test machines and i see it in ccmcache folder. Looking at execmgr.log it executed the following:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c sfc.cmd, Working Directory = C:\Windows\ccmcache\g\

Running "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c sfc.cmd with 32bitLauncher
```

Those two indicators were noted around 4:43PM. I don't see exit code 0 or any other code. Then looking at cbs.log the last write time was 4:19PM. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If I try to run sfc /scannow from a 32Bit cmd in 64Bit Windows I get an error so you probably have to use a trick to run the 64bit sfc.

Instead of the commandline

`cmd /c sfc.cmd`

use

`C:\windows\sysnative\cmd /c sfc.cmd`

[Sysnative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector) is an alias that you can unfortunately not see but if a program is started as 32bit process it can access it. What it does is avoiding the WoW64 redirection that intercepts every call to system32 and sends it to syswow64 which in your case leads to a problem.